# Mysterious files appearing in airflow composer environment

Tags: logging, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a question about some mystery files that continually appear in our airflow composer GCS bucket. In addition to the folders that I expect to see (dags, logs, etc) in our GCS bucket, we seem to have a whole bunch of files and folders with meaningless names such as `ebee13da5-3e2e-4d36-825d-cce18b70e804-526b92e0-06da-47ff-97e3-57da1cac3002-build`. Here is the contents of one of these files, it seems to just be some sort of log file:

```
name: "operations/f72987cd-8e61-4507-b22d-829e7f2bcfe8"
done: true
sequence_number: 3
response: "Airflow services are ready now"
env_var_update_metadata {
  stage: UPDATE_FINISHED
  description: ""
}
```

However, that doesn't clear things up for me, because I expect logs to get saved into the log folder, not into this top level. I haven't been able to find any documentation explaining what these files are or where they come from.

- What is the purpose of these files?
- What creates them? Is it Airflow or Composer? Are they only created during some specific event, eg perhaps when we upgrade the environment?
- Can I safely delete them, or is that going to break things?
- Can I reconfigure something somewhere so that these files save into a folder, and don't clutter up the top level of our bucket?

If its relevant, we are running `composer-2.1.1-airflow-2.3.4`.

Here is another example file:

```
name: "operations/cd252dc8-162e-42da-bdb7-3e7fb38e378e"
done: true
sequence_number: 3
response: "The custom package dependencies are now installed."
pypi_update_metadata {
  stage: ROLLOUT_FINISHED
  unblock_gae_creation: false
  description: ""
}
```